# PHP header image-type output vs Location redirect to binary in fs

Tags: php, image, curl, header, filesystems

I'm trying to determine if I should just directly

1) have PHP fetch an image binary and output (with header as image-type) image, eg:

```
/* $image = ... insert curl function to fetch image */

header('Content-Type: image/png');

echo $image;
```

or if I should have

2) a header redirect to the URL path of the image

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/pathtoimage/image.png');
```

---

Some initial questions:

In the first, would that amount to any overhead with PHP having to have the image in memory in order to output it?

In the second, would this lead to any errors on clients that somehow cannot follow the PHP header redirect?

Comment: I just did something similar and would be interested if anyone has run any tests (I may do some of my own eventually).  For now I've gone with the redirect, that way there's less chance of me breaking something.

Comment: No php-genius actually figured this out? @Pietrosanti have you done some testing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm against header -> location solution as you will add an extra request to your server. 
Try this solution instead:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
```

This solution should have minimal overhead and memory occupation.